# Free Space not shown in partiton even after extending it through gparted

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, disk-space, ubuntu-12.04

I have a Ubuntu machine running 12.04 LTS on it. I had a very small "/" partition at the beginning, say of 16 GB. Now i added a 50 GB to it which i split from another partition and added to the "/". All the process has been done through gparted. Even after extending the partition, it still doesn't show that 50GB in as free space. Te 50 GB i added is shown as used, the free space still remains close to 1GB which was the same before extending the partition. Any Suggestions?

Comment: The partition size does not necessarily equal the filesystem size. You should use resize2fs to check this. Consult the manual on usage `man resize2fs`.

Comment: @Informaficker but does doing that cause a data loss on my device ?

Comment: normally it is safe, anyway you should always make a backup before resizing partitions.

Comment: Please add the output of `df` to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Resize your filesystem using `resize2fs`.

Comment: `gparted` does this for you.

Comment: @psusi Does it do so even if started from a live CD/USB?

Comment: @psusi i have already done this using  gparted in live cd mode.

Comment: of course, that is the usual way one runs it.

Comment: I would still try to resize the filesystem using `resize2fs` (run as root (`sudo resize2fs` on Ubuntu)). You can create a backup of your data first if you have a safety concern.